# DialogFragment showing AlertDialog with Adapter does not survive orientation change

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, illegalstateexception, android-orientation, android-dialogfragment

I have hit a wall on this one. My DialogFragment works well with all other dialogs I have except for the one that uses a customer Adapter. When changing orientation the second time I get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment NewAlertDialog{447bc528} not attached to Activity` This is using the API 4+ Support package.

It doesn't happen on the first orientation change, it always happens on the second, meaning it happens in this order with the dialog showing:

- Portrait -> Landscape -> Portrait -> java.lang.IllegalStateException
- Landscape -> Portrait -> Landscape -> java.lang.IllegalStateException

Here is the dialog:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final DialogItem[] items = {
                new DialogItem(getString(R.string.test1), R.drawable.test1),
                new DialogItem(getString(R.string.test2), R.drawable.test2),
            };
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<DialogItem>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,
            android.R.id.text1,
            items){
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                    tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(items[position].icon, 0, 0, 0);
                    int dp10 = (int) (10 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
                    tv.setCompoundDrawablePadding(dp10);
                    return v;
                }
            };
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle(R.string.title)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                            if (item == 0)
                                doThis();
                            else
                                doThat();
                        }
                    }).create();
}
```

This is a DialogItem:

```
class DialogItem {
    public final String text;
    public final int icon;
    public DialogItem(String text, Integer icon) {
        this.text = text;
        this.icon = icon;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

I know it is a problem with containing an Adapter because if I remove the `.setAdapter()` call from `AlertDialog.Builder` then the problem goes away.

Also odd is that there is NO PROBLEM on my ICS device. This only happens on the Gingerbread device I test on. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Matt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. Calling getResources() resources off the Activity instead of the DialogFragment was the necessary change.

Before:

```
int dp10 = (int) (10 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
```

After:

```
int dp10 = (int) (10 * getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
```